# Make group of parameters mandatory

Tags: powershell, arguments

How can I make PowerShell script to accept 0 or 3 params? All or nothing.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    # Name of VPN connection
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True,Position=1)]
    [string]$vpn_name,

    # Server URL or IP
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True,Position=2)]
    [string]$vpn_server,

    # 192.168.72.0/24
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True,Position=3)]
    [string[]]$target_nets
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simplified snippet

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    # Name of VPN connection
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName="WithParams")]
    [string]$name,  

    # Server URL or IP
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName="WithParams"))]
    [string]$vpn_server,


    # No params
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True,Position=0, ParameterSetName="NoParams")]
    [string]$none
)

# Then check what parameters set was passed
switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName){
    "WithParams"  { Write-Host $name; break}
    "NoParams"    { Write-Host "No params passed."; break }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=0, ParameterSet="FirstSet")]
    [string]FirstRequiredParam,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$False, Position=0, ParameterSet="SecondSet")]
    [string]FirstNotRequiredParam
)
```

Comment: close to working solution. should be `ParameterSetName` .

Comment: ` it works?` yes. thank you. I have found more info.